# NextJs not displaying data from API calls after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, next.js, vercel

I got a nextJS app deployed to vercel but I'm having a strange issue with it. Its making API calls to my backend which isn't hosted publicly yet, I am running it on my local machine. The backend is a rails API-only server. In the console log for the rails server, I can see the requests being sent to the server from the deployed website on vercel however the data is not displayed on the website for some reason. I am using `useEffect()` instead of the `getStaticProps()` method for all API calls on the nextjs app so could that be causing the issue?

I have also made sure to include the URL of the vercel app in my rails `cors.rb` file. I am new to both rails and nextjs so if anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I'm a little confused - is your Next.js site hosted on Vercel and the Ruby backend hosted locally on your computer?  Look at the network request in the browser's developer tools to see if the data comes back to the app.  This will determine if it's the request or the app.  In Chrome, you open dev tools, click on the network request route, i.e., `/` then the response tab.